# Docker - no matching manifest for docker-compose build but docker build works when using non-default docker context

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having an issue building via `docker-compose build` but not via `docker build` when using a non-default docker context.  Am I doing something wrong?  Or does docker-compose not support contexts properly ... or ?

I am running on a mac with two docker contexts, `default` context refers to a standard vm running linux while second context is a windows server virtualbox vm.
(I also love running with scissors ...)

I have a `Dockerfile` that FROM's a windows image.  `docker build .` works fine when using the windows context.
I have created a `docker-compose.yml` file that attempts to refer to that `Dockerfile` to build.  `docker-compose build` fails with the error "no matching manifest".  This is true regardless of which context I am in.

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:aspnetapp
```

And in the parent dir, the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
```

And the output of `docker build .` and `docker-compose build` and `docker version` and `docker context ls`

```
11:52:42 ~/proj/k/docker/web (master) $ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/1 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:aspnetapp
 ---> bd698e59f147
Successfully built bd698e59f147
11:52:45 ~/proj/k/docker/web (master) $ cd ..
11:56:38 ~/proj/k/docker (master) $ docker-compose build
Building web
Step 1/1 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:aspnetapp
aspnetapp: Pulling from dotnet/framework/samples
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
11:56:43 ~/proj/k/docker (master) $ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:22:34 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       2ee0c57608
  Built:            11/13/2019 07:58:51
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
11:56:49 ~/proj/k/docker (master) $ docker context ls
NAME                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT               KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
2019-box *          2019-box windows-docker-machine           tcp://192.168.99.90:2376                            
default             Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                         swarm
11:56:52 ~/proj/k/docker (master) $
```

Comment: How are you controlling which of your two Docker contexts is being used by `docker-compose`?

Comment: I am "assuming" that docker-compose knows to use the current docker context.  But maybe that is the issue?  How should I specify a non-default context for compose?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect -- but I am not certain -- that `docker-compose` doesn't know anything about "contexts". That means you control which Docker instance to use by setting the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable (which is also understood by the `docker` client).

To talk to a remote (network connected) host:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://hostname:port
```

To talk to a Unix socket:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

To have docker use `https` rather than `http`, set the `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` variable:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

See "[Protect the Docker daemon socket](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/#secure-by-default)" for some documentation around these variables.

Comment: Thx, @larsks ... I think you may be on right track but setting DOCKER_HOST to the endpoint that `docker context` shows (in my case, `tcp://192.168.99.90:2376` as above) produces an error from `docker version`: "Error response from daemon: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server."
Any thought on how to determine value for `DOCKER_HOST`?

Comment: Hi @larsks - thx for thoughts!  Tried this ... if `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` is set at all (value does not seem to matter), client looks for `~/.docker/ca.pem` and won't try to connect if it does not exist.  This is not needed for `docker build`.  So does not help.  But good thought~

Comment: I actually think that's exactly what you want: if you're connecting to an SSL endpoint, you do need the CA file so that Docker can validate the connection. I use exactly that in my local setup using a local, SSL-accessible Docker instance.

Comment: If you *really* want to skip TLS verification you can set `DOCKER_TLS` instead of `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY`.

Comment: Well, I really want docker-compose to behave the same way that docker does.

Comment: I'm not sure in what way this doesn't answer your question. Both docker and docker-compose recognize the DOCKER_HOST and DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY environment variables (it looks as if compose doesn't recgonize DOCKER_TLS). If you set them, both tools will behave the same way. This seems to exactly solve the question you're asking.

Comment: you were on the right track, but missing a setting or two.  The easy way to get the list of vars and values needed is `docker-machine env contextname` - this will spew the vals needed in a form suitable for `eval`.  thx for help -- i will accept if you can update ans.

Comment: What I've documented here is what I'm actually using, so it demonstrably works, but I'm not working with `docker machine`.  If additional configuration is necessary when working with `docker machine` I'm happy to update if you can leave that information in a comment.

Comment: Output from `docker-machine env 2019-box` ("2019-box" is the name of the context):
`export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"`
`export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.90:2376"`
`export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/bhazard/.docker/machine/machines/2019-box"`
`export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="2019-box"`

This is the incantation that worked for me.  So to your earlier advice, this keeps secure and includes the cert path (missing element for me)